# Animate transition to new height for container div when elements removed from container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a filter with jQuery to remove some elements from a div when clicked. I use `opacity:0` and `visibilty:hidden` so there is a fade animation to these elements when they are filtered. After the fade animation I then use `display:none` to remove them from the div. If they are then unfiltered again, they are set to `display:block` and set `opacity:1` to animate them reappearing.

When the contents of the div are "removed" using `display:none`, the height of the container div instantly sets to it's new shorter height. **I would like the container div to shorten to it's new height with an animation, rather than instantly changing height.** Is there a way to do this with my solution so far?

I was expecting that adding `transition: all 0.35s ease-in` would work when the contents were removed, but it just changes instantly to it's new height. **As this is a responsive design the height is not fixed, it varies at different screen widths.**

The code can be viewed at the following jsfiddle...
https://jsfiddle.net/qv5vrz6c/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem of playing with display property to show/hide an element is you can't apply CSS transitions on it.

However, you can use the `height` of the element with an `overflow:hidden;` to do the trick :

```
.web-box, .game-box{
  transition:all 0.5s;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.web-box.mp-hide, .game-box.mp-hide{
  height: 0;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/qv5vrz6c/2/)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot for this answer.